# How to perform Real Time Yolo3 Object Detection from 4 cameras streaming asynchronous

Tags: python, stream, camera, object-detection

I have implemented a python app that performs real time car_model and license plate recognition from a camera using yolo3 / opencv- gpu. Frames are captured in Threading having a descent fps.
I am trying to update it by getting streaming from 4 cameras showing the frames to a pysimplegui window. However I can't figure out how to make stream from the cameras run in parallel. It seems that each stream is waiting from the previous one to finish in order to stream a frame, so the overall fps, drops to 1/4.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Results.num_cam = 2
    # initialize the video streams and allow them to warmup
    img_size_x, img_size_y = 1280, 800
    window = create_window(img_size_x, img_size_y,Results.num_cam)
    print("[INFO] starting cameras...")

    prev_frame_time = 0
    prev_frame_time = 0
    if Results.num_cam == 2:
        webcam1 = VideoStream(src='rtsp://admin:VVZOZR@192.168.1.11:554/11').start()
        webcam2 = VideoStream(src='rtsp://admin:VVZOZR@192.168.1.11:554/11').start()
    else:
        webcam1 = VideoStream(src='rtsp://admin:VVZOZR@192.168.1.11:554/11').start()
        webcam2 = VideoStream(src='rtsp://admin:VVZOZR@192.168.1.11:554/11').start()
        webcam3 = VideoStream(src='rtsp://admin:VVZOZR@192.168.1.11:554/11').start()
        webcam4 = VideoStream(src='rtsp://admin:VVZOZR@192.168.1.11:554/11').start()

    time.sleep(2.0)
    Results.car_m, Results.car_l, _ = yolo_cars()
    Results.pl_m, Results.pl_l, _ = yolo_plate()
    # initialize the two motion detectors, along with the total
    # number of frames read
    results = Results()
    total = 0
    while True:
        # initialize image elements objects
        if Results.num_cam == 2:
            cam_view = window['-FRAME1-']
            cam1_view = window['-FRAME2-']
        else:
            cam_view = window['-FRAME1-']
            cam1_view = window['-FRAME2-']
            cam2_view = window['-FRAME3-']
            cam3_view = window['-FRAME4-']
        # initialize the list of frames that have been processed
        frames = []
        event, ts = window.read(timeout=0.05)
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        # loop over the frames and their respective motion detectors
        if Results.num_cam == 2:
            res_all = (results, results)
            web_all = (webcam1, webcam2)
        else:
            res_all = (results, results, results, results)
            web_all = (webcam1, webcam2, webcam3, webcam4)
        for (stream, res) in zip(web_all, res_all):
            # read the next frame from the video stream and resize
            frame = stream.read()
            res_inst = res.process_frame(frame,True)
            if total < 32:
                frames.append(res_inst.frame)
                continue
            # update the frames list
            frames.append(res_inst.frame)
            # increment the total number of frames read and grab the
            # current timestamp
        total += 1
        if Results.num_cam == 2:
            for (frame, name) in zip(frames, (cam_view, cam1_view)):  # , 'Webcam3', 'Webcam4')):
                name.update(frame)
        else:
            for (frame, name) in zip(frames, (cam_view, cam1_view, cam2_view, cam3_view)):
                name.update(frame)

        new_frame_time = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (new_frame_time - prev_frame_time)
        prev_frame_time = new_frame_time
        fps = int(fps)

        window['-FR-'].update(str(fps))
    # do a bit of cleanup
    print("[INFO] cleaning up...")
    for web in web_all:
        web.stop()`.
```

Comment: `window.read(timeout=0.05)` where the argument `timeout` is in milliseconds to wait until the `read` will return if no other GUI events happen first.

Comment: Do you think that this is the problem? I used alternatively opencv imshow but the outcome was similar

Comment: It's clear that your script is not complete and executable for any one here. I just point out one issue when I first time and quick view on it. It's better to start it from only one camera, then more after it work. I didn't find any threading in your code.

Comment: You are right! It is impossible to send the whole code that includes 14 scripts and 3 classes. However the concepts remains the same.  There are 2or 4 instances from a class Videostream that streams a camera in frame threading. Each frame is inserted in the class instance Results that makes the detection/recognition. Finally each processed frame is inserted in the image element of the pysimplegui window. One camera stream returns, with no process of the frames, an fps of 24 but 2 cameras stream returns fps12. I would like to keep the same fps regardless the number of streams.